# Is there a file size limit for Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After running successfully the bash script stop working
This line is producing an error:

> move failed: ../../../../Users/thisuser/Desktop/somefile.zip to s3://cloudbackups/somefile.zip ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))

```
aws s3 mv $source_file_path $target_path
```

the source file is more than 8GB. Mac OS.

Answer (score 8):

From [S3 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> Q:     **How much data can I store in Amazon S3?**
>
> The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a minimum of 0 bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes. For objects larger than 100 megabytes, customers should consider using the [Multipart Upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html) capability.)

**While the maximum file size is 5TB, the maximum size for a single PUT operation is 5GB** - this means you will be unable to upload an 8GB file with a single operation, and **you need to use multipart upload**.  Note that AWS recommends multipart upload for any files larger than 100MB.

Multipart uploads have huge reliability advantages - failures and retries are limited in size and scope. In order to do this via command line interface, you'll need to familiarize yourself with multiple different commands [documented here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/)

For more details on multipart upload see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html):

> - Improved throughput - You can upload parts in parallel to improve throughput.
> - Quick recovery from any network issues - Smaller part size minimizes the impact of restarting a failed upload due to a network error.
> - Pause and resume object uploads - You can upload object parts over time. Once you initiate a multipart upload there is no expiry; you must explicitly complete or abort the multipart upload.
> - Begin an upload before you know the final object size - You can upload an object as you are creating it.

Comment: "aws s3 mv" is a  high-level command
From the links above
The recommended method is to use aws s3 commands (such as aws s3 cp) for multipart uploads and downloads, because these aws s3 commands automatically perform multipart uploading and downloading based on the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 has a file size limit of 5TB, so that clearly isn't your issue.

The `Broken Pipe` message suggests a networking problem. Copying an 8GB file makes it more susceptible to networking issues.

I would suggest retrying it, especially if the failure occurs at different positions each time. If possible, use a more reliable network (eg corporate network vs home network).

You can also activate debug by appending `--debug` to your command. This might provide additional information to investigate the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by "different positions"?

Comment: I mean if it seems to break a different points in the upload, such as after 3 seconds and the next time after 15 seconds, etc. This indicates that it is not a consistent error, which would suggest network problems rather than a specific system error.

Answer (score 0):

Object size limit on S3 is 5TB but single PUT limit is 5GB.

Also, to upload big files on S3 it is generally good to use Multipart Upload  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html)

Comment: "aws s3 cp provides a shell-like copy command, and automatically performs a multipart upload to transfer large files quickly and resiliently." from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

Comment: Can you try running your command with screen utility. That will ensure that your terminal session does not break.

Comment: What is screen utility? Client's computer is running MAC OS

Comment: Screen utility helps to manage long SSH session. This blog explain screen utility in detail - http://www.kinnetica.com/2011/05/29/using-screen-on-mac-os-x/ . Hope this helps. Kindly feel free to accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: Same error happen after running screen then script "move failed...Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL..."